# How to update a value by jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I load content of a page by jQuery AJAX as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#next').click(function(event){
  $.ajax({
  url: "load.php?start="+$('#lastid').text(), 
   success: function(html){
   $("#results").append(html);
   $("#lastid").empty().load('html #start');
   }
  });
 });
});
```

In the current document, I have `<div id="lastid"></div>` and in the external php file `<div id="start"></div>`

The value for id="start" is updated from database, and it will be transferred to id="lastid". However, this code only works for FIRST click. For default `<div id="lastid">1</div>`, when clicking the button (id="more") it will read load.php?start=1 and updates the current document to `<div id="lastid">11</div>` (it's visible). But the second click will not load `load.php?start=11`

It seems that `$('lastid')` well reads the default value of `<div id="lastid"></div>`, but NOT when it has been updated by `$("#lastid").empty().load('html #start')`

How can I modify this code to work for subsequent clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate,
What I see from you code is that you are attaching an event once the page is loaded. And this creates a static call with static values that don't get updated as you continue.
My suggestions is to use a function that will feed an Id dynamically to your ajax call as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on("click", '#next', function(event){
  $.ajax({
   url: buildurl(), 
   success: function(html){
   $("#results").append(html);
   $("#lastid").empty().load('html #start');
   }
  });
 });
});

function buildurl()
{
   return "load.php?start="+ $('#lastid').text();
}
```

This will force your event to always call this function and the function to get a fresh value from lastid.
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Wow, what a mess! Let's clean up a bit :)

You need to get rid of the id, as an id has to be unique and if you load another div with id lastId into your site, jQuery will not know which id to get. If you have many divs, each containing the id, you can just read the last id by using ('div:last').text();

So your ajax would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#next').click(function(event){
  $.ajax({
   url: "load.php", 
   data: "start="+$('div:last').text()
   success: function(html){
     $("#results").append(html);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

I also don't know what you do with the last line in the success, as load should be used to load data from the server with ajax, what is what you do by using $.ajax(). Also load() takes at least an url as parameter, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: +1 for the mess I made ;) I used load() to parse data caught by ajax to get the value of start (which is updated in load.php upon every run). In your code, the value of `last` is constant, as it comes from load.php

Answer (score 1):

try .live() function instead of .click()

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your success function because you have multiple `#lastid` when clicking twice.

try something like:

```
success: function(html){
    $("#lastid").removeAttr("id");  // remove's the id from #lastid
    $("#results").append(html);     // appends the new one
    $("#lastid").empty().load('html #start');
}
```